# using threads to sort chunks of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sorting, javafx

So I need to make my program to use threads to sort the chunks of an array using the specific sorting method (insertion/bubble/quick/selection) that the user chose. then after those threads are done, create other threads that will merge the chunks back together into the sorted array.

my code so far is a GUI that asks a user to select from 4 radio buttons(bubble,insertion,selection,quick) then has the user select where the array is already sorted, randomly sorted, or reverse sorted. Then the user selects the array Size and the Block(chunk) size and hits go  and then it sorts that method and outputs the sorted method to the console. How can I change my code to use threads instead to merge the chunks? 
here is my code:

```
        package sorting;

import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class sorting extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane rootPane = new BorderPane();
        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        rootPane.setCenter(gp);
        gp.setVgap(5);
        gp.setHgap(5);
        rootPane.prefWidth(700);
        rootPane.prefHeight(400);
        gp.prefWidth(400);
        gp.prefHeight(400);
        Label sort = new Label(" Sorting Algorithm ");
        RadioButton selection = new RadioButton("selection ");
        RadioButton bubble = new RadioButton("bubble ");
        RadioButton insertion = new RadioButton("insertion");
        RadioButton quick = new RadioButton("Quick ");
        Label inputType = new Label(" Input Type ");
        RadioButton sorted = new RadioButton("Already Sorted ");
        RadioButton reverse = new RadioButton("Reverse ");
        RadioButton random = new RadioButton("Random ");
        Label inputSize = new Label(" Input Size: ");
        TextField inputText = new TextField();

        inputText.setOnAction((ActionEvent inputText1) -> {
            String inputText2 = inputText.getText();
            double inputText3 = Double.parseDouble(inputText2);
            System.out.println(inputText3);
        });
        Label blockSize = new Label(" Block Size: ");
        TextField block = new TextField();

        block.setOnAction((ActionEvent block1) -> {
            String block2 = block.getText();
            double block3 = Double.parseDouble(block2);
            System.out.println(block3);
        });

        Button go = new Button("Go ");
        ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();

        selection.setToggleGroup(tg);
        selection.setSelected(true);
        bubble.setToggleGroup(tg);
        insertion.setToggleGroup(tg);
        quick.setToggleGroup(tg);
        ToggleGroup tg1 = new ToggleGroup();
        sorted.setToggleGroup(tg1);
        sorted.setSelected(true);
        reverse.setToggleGroup(tg1);
        random.setToggleGroup(tg1);

        gp.add(sort, 0, 0);
        gp.add(selection, 0, 1);
        gp.add(bubble, 0, 2);
        gp.add(insertion, 0, 3);
        gp.add(quick, 0, 4);
        gp.add(inputType, 0, 7);
        gp.add(sorted, 0, 8);
        gp.add(reverse, 0, 9);
        gp.add(random, 0, 10);
        gp.add(inputSize, 0, 12);
        gp.add(inputText, 1, 12);
        gp.add(blockSize, 0, 13);
        gp.add(block, 1, 13);
        gp.add(go, 0, 16);

        go.setOnAction((ActionEvent go1) -> {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //selection sorted
            if (selection.isSelected() && sorted.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getSorted(arraySize, true);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                selectionSort(array);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

            }//selction sorted reverse
            else if (selection.isSelected() && reverse.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getSorted(arraySize, true);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                array = getReverse(array);
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                selectionSort(array);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            } //selection sorted random
            else if (selection.isSelected() && random.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getRandom(arraySize);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                selectionSort(array);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            }//quick sort random
            else if (quick.isSelected() && random.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getRandom(arraySize);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

            }//quick sort sorted
            else if (quick.isSelected() && sorted.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getSorted(arraySize, true);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            }//quick reverse sort
            else if (quick.isSelected() && reverse.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getSorted(arraySize, true);
                array = getReverse(array);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            }//insertion sorted sort
            else if (insertion.isSelected() && sorted.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getSorted(arraySize, true);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                insertionSort(array);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            }//insertion random sort
            else if (insertion.isSelected() && random.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getRandom(arraySize);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                insertionSort(array);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            }//insertion reverse
            else if (insertion.isSelected() && reverse.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getSorted(arraySize, true);
                array = getReverse(array);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                insertionSort(array);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            }//bubble sort
            else if (bubble.isSelected() && sorted.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getSorted(arraySize, true);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                bubbleSort(array);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            }//bubble random sort
            else if (bubble.isSelected() && random.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getRandom(arraySize);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                bubbleSort(array);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            }//bubble reverse sort
            else if (bubble.isSelected() && reverse.isSelected()) {
                int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputText.getText());
                int[] array = getSorted(arraySize, true);
                System.out.println("unsorted: ");
                array = getReverse(array);
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                bubbleSort(array);
                System.out.println("sorted: ");
                print(array, Integer.parseInt(block.getText()));
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            }
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Thread Sorted!");
            alert.setHeaderText("Finished");
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
            alert.setContentText("Sort completed in " + totalTime + " milliseconds ");
            alert.showAndWait();

        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 500, 350);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Project 4");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }
//insertion sort

    public static void insertionSort(int array[]) {
        // int loopCount = 0;
        int n = array.length;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            int key = array[j];
            int i = j - 1;
            while ((i > -1) && (array[i] > key)) {
                array[i + 1] = array[i];
                i--;

            }
            array[i + 1] = key;
        }
        //return loopCount;
    }
//quick sort

    int partition(int arr[], int left, int right) {
        int i = left, j = right;
        int tmp;
        int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }
            while (arr[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        return i;
    }
//quick sort

    public void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
        int index = partition(arr, left, right);
        if (left < index - 1) {
            quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
        }
        if (index < right) {
            quickSort(arr, index, right);
        }
        //return index;
    }
//bubble sort

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
        int n = arr.length;
        //  int loopCount = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
                if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                    temp = arr[j - 1];
                    arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }

            }
        }
        //return loopCount;
    }
//selection sort

    public static void selectionSort(int[] arr) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int index = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[j] < arr[index]) {
                    index = j;
                }

            }
            int smallerNumber = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;
        }

    }

    public static int[] getRandom(int size) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] array = new int[size];
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            array[i - 1] = Math.abs(rand.nextInt()) % 100;
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static int[] getSorted(int size, boolean accending) {
        int[] array = new int[size];
        if (accending) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
                array[i - 1] = i;
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
                array[size - i] = i;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static int[] getReverse(int[] arrayw) {
        int[] array = new int[arrayw.length];
        for (int i = 0, j = array.length - 1; i < array.length; i++, j--) {
            array[j] = arrayw[i];
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void print(int[] array, int blockSize) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
            if ((i + 1) % blockSize == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from your specific problem, I will post a piece of code that works on an array of data in a concurrent way. 
In the code, 2 threads are created. Each of them works on a separated portion of the array. Each thread reads the boundaries of the portion of its array by the from and to variables. 
The code is pretty straightforward, so I think it's not difficult to understand what it's doing.

```
    package pk1;

    class Work implements Runnable {

        final public int size = 100;
        private int[] a = new int[size];
        public int[] from = new int[2];
        public int[] to = new int[2];

        public void run() {
        int tn = Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for (int k = from[tn]; k <= to[tn]; k++) {
            a[k] = a[k] ^ 2;

            System.out.println("Working on element " + (tn == 1 ? "\t" : "") + k);
            try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        }

    }

    public class C1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Work w1 = new Work();

        w1.from[0] = 0;
        w1.to[0] = w1.size / 2 - 1;

        w1.from[1] = w1.size / 2;
        w1.to[1] = w1.size - 1;

        Thread t1 = new Thread(w1, "0");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(w1, "1");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        while (t1.isAlive() || t2.isAlive())
            try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: so then for my code I should make a seperate class and follow your example to implement it in my code? @Mario